# Casting problems when trying to be generic / 'type free' | ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

**Question**

Is there a way to define a method only once in C# (in a helper class or something) not knowing which type is given to be returned?

**Long explanation**
I get the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[WerkStageNu.Vacancies]'
>   to type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[WerkStageNu.Models.IFilteredEntities]'.

I have a ListingsController which does a Search through my current Vacancies in the database:

```
public ActionResult Search(int? page, string branchid, string hoursago, string jobtypeid, string educationlevelid, string careerlevelid)
    {
        string searchResult = string.Empty;
        const int pageSize = 10;

        IQueryable<IFilteredEntities> selectedListings = (IQueryable<IFilteredEntities>)Repository.Instance._entities.Vacancies.AsQueryable();

        Dictionary<string, string> filterParams = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
            {"branchid", branchid}, {"hoursago", hoursago}, {"jobtypeid", jobtypeid}, {"educationlevelid", educationlevelid}, {"careerlevelid", careerlevelid}};

        selectedListings = FilterByIDHelper.Filter(selectedListings, filterParams);

        var paginatedDinners = new PaginatedList<Vacancies>(((IQueryable<Vacancies>)selectedListings).ToList(), page ?? 0, pageSize);
        return View("Index", paginatedDinners);

    }
```

Now, this search is just for Vacancies. But one can imagine we have searches all over the place all in general the same routine so I want to call the same method getting back different types. For this case I have made an Interface , IFilteredEntities. In my partial class Vacancies (partial class, class Vacancies is generated by my DB entity framework) I just do:

```
public partial class Vacancies : IFilteredEntities
```

And of course implement the methods in the Interface which are not implemented by Default. In my Interface I have:

```
    interface IFilteredEntities
{
    string EducationLevelID { get; set; }
    string BrancheID { get; set; }
    string CareerLevelID { get; set; }
    string JobTypeID { get; set; }

    Branches Branches { get; set; }
    DateTime? DateOfCreation { get; set; }
    CareerLevels CareerLevels { get; set; }
    JobTypes JobTypes { get; set; }
    EducationLevels EducationLevels { get; set; }
}
```

For convenience I have uploaded the two helper classes PaginatedList and FilterCriteriaHelper [here](http://www.bastijn.nl/zooi/PaginatedList.cs) and [here](http://www.bastijn.nl/zooi/FilterCriteriaHelper.cs).

Now, the method which would do the actual filtering is placed inside another helper class: FilterByIDHelper.cs.

```
 public static IQueryable<IFilteredEntities> Filter(IQueryable<IFilteredEntities> collection, Dictionary<string, string> filterParams)
    {
        if (filterParams.ContainsKey("branchid")) collection = FilterByBranchId(collection, filterParams["branchid"]);
        if (filterParams.ContainsKey("hoursago")) collection = FilterByHoursAgo(collection, filterParams["hoursago"]);
        if (filterParams.ContainsKey("jobtypeid")) collection = FilterByJobTypeId(collection, filterParams["jobtypeid"]);
        if (filterParams.ContainsKey("educationlevelid")) collection = FilterByEducationLevelId(collection, filterParams["educationlevelid"]);
        if (filterParams.ContainsKey("careerlevelid")) collection = FilterByCareerLevelId(collection, filterParams["careerlevelid"]);

        return collection;
    }

public static IQueryable<IFilteredEntities> Filter(IQueryable<IFilteredEntities> collection, Dictionary<string, string> filterParams)
    {
        if (filterParams.ContainsKey("branchid")) collection = FilterByBranchId(collection, filterParams["branchid"]);
        if (filterParams.ContainsKey("hoursago")) collection = FilterByHoursAgo(collection, filterParams["hoursago"]);
        if (filterParams.ContainsKey("jobtypeid")) collection = FilterByJobTypeId(collection, filterParams["jobtypeid"]);
        if (filterParams.ContainsKey("educationlevelid")) collection = FilterByEducationLevelId(collection, filterParams["educationlevelid"]);
        if (filterParams.ContainsKey("careerlevelid")) collection = FilterByCareerLevelId(collection, filterParams["careerlevelid"]);

        return collection;
    }
```

For convenience here is a picture of a part of my solution explorer:

[Solution Explorer http://www.bastijn.nl/zooi/solutionexplorer.png](http://www.bastijn.nl/zooi/solutionexplorer.png)

**In short:**

What I try to do is instead of calling like:

```
selectedListings = Repository.Instance._entities.Vacancies.AsQueryable();
Dictionary<string, string> filterParams = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
        {"branchid", branchid}, {"hoursago", hoursago}, {"jobtypeid", jobtypeid}, {"educationlevelid", educationlevelid}, {"careerlevelid", careerlevelid}};

    selectedListings = FilterByIDHelper.Filter(selectedListings, filterParams);

    var paginatedDinners = new PaginatedList<Vacancies>(selectedListings.ToList(), page ?? 0, pageSize);
    return View("Index", paginatedDinners);
```

Call the variant shown up, using an Interface so I only have to define te "Filter" method once instead of for all classes / models. *Now Notice that all of this DOES compile!* The problem is that I get the following error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[WerkStageNu.Vacancies]' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[WerkStageNu.Models.IFilteredEntities]'.
```

I hope I have not forgotten any information but I'm already staring at this code for some while. Might forget a relation or something, just ask for it if I did :).

**-----------------------------------------------------**

**EDIT AFTER COMMENTS**

**-----------------------------------------------------**

O crap, nevermind this part, I forgot to as AsEnumerable, was still using AsQueryable.

Comment: Bonus points for the sheer effort you put into the question!

Comment: Thanks a lot, bonus points will be given for the person putting as many effort in his or her reply :).

Comment: Uh what? I guess not :).

Comment: Maybe you should tag this as c# also. Its not only specific to ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: I think, Mastermind means monster.com :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like this is a covariance vs. contravariance issue.  Basically, an `IQueryable<Vacancies>` is not a sub-type of `IQueryable<IFilteredEntities>`, even though Vacancies implements IFilteredEntities.  Thus, the line with the cast is causing a runtime error.  So rather than doing the cast try this instead:

```
IEnumerable<IFilteredEntities> selectedListings =
    Repository.Instance._entities.Vacancies.AsQueryable()
    .OfType<IFilteredEntities>();
```

What this will do is project each element of the collection to an IFilteredEntities type.

Another option is to rewrite your filter methods so they use generics, like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Filter<T>(
    IEnumerable<T> collection, IDictionary<string, string> filterParams)
    where T : IFilteredEntities
{
    ...
}
```

This would then allow you to pass in a collection containing any type that derives from IFilteredEntities and get back a collection of the same type.  And if you're using C# 3, you don't even have to specify the type parameter if it can be implicitly determined by the compiler.

Comment: I have edited my post at the bottom with the problems I achieve after implementing this. It does pass the line but the next part is complaining :).

Comment: Wups, with the minor addition to change: AsQueryable() into AsEnumerable().